# Why can't i RemoveAllObjects of NSMutableArray in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I'm developing a app in Searching with sqlite database using ARC.

I have to retrieve data from database into NSMutableArray to show retrieved data when textDidChange Event of UISearchBar.

It's has alot of data retrieve from database when textDidChange of UISearchBar.

After retrieved alot of data from database,i have always clear from NSMutableArray with following codes.

```
[self.myArrayData removeAllObjects];
```

However i remove all of data from NSMutableArray , memory allocations are still occurring.
Not reduced.

Next time when i type something in UISearchBar, memory allocations are still increasing.
After i typed 10 times or above,I receive memory warning from XCodes and out of memory.

I want to know why data from NSMutableArray isn't clear when i called removeAllObjects method.
I am developing my app with ARC.
Please help me.

Comment: You need to provide more context.

Comment: How do you know the memory is associated with the array?

Comment: I used to track with Instrument tool.After i typed 10 times,It's take 100MB memory.I had also use RemoveAllObject.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question;  *How do you know that 100MB of memory is even remotely associated with the array?!*   If you removeAllObjects, the objects are removed.   They will only be deallocated if they are no longer retained by anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a lot of information here but it may not be NSMutableArray holding on to the data.  SQLite also keeps a cache of recently retrieved records.  You can reduce/remove the SQLCache by executing this after you've opened the database.  Set the cache size to the number of pages you want SQLite to cache.  The default is 2000.  Each page is 1024 bytes in size.

```
    const char *pragmaSql = "PRAGMA cache_size = 0";
    if (sqlite3_exec(database, pragmaSql, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to execute pragma statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
```

EDIT: Technically you can't reduce the cache below 10.  If you try, the program will simply set the cache to 10.

Comment: But after i search in 50 times,there is a error occurred in your statement.
"Could not be loaded database."  That is. XCodes also show error in your lines. What is that error? How can i solve that?

Comment: You say that an error occurs in the code I posted only after you search 50 times?  My code should only be run once when you open the database.  That should only happen once, usually when the app starts.  Some people will close/reopen a database to clear the cache, but since you're setting the cache_size to 0, you don't need to do that.  You really shouldn't be closing/opening the database for each search.  Instead, just keep the database open.

Answer (score 1):

if after `[self.myArrayData removeAllObjects];` `[self.myArrayData count] == 0` you can be sure that your array has removed its objects and decremented their retain counts... but if other objects still own them they they wont actually be `dealloc`'ed... so the objects may be over-`retained` and therefor leaked or they may just be owned by something else.